# Set Antykwa Torunska to use Old Style Numbers in body text, instead of just small caps

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums, antykwatorunska

Is there a way to get Antykwa Torunska to use its old style numbers character set by default in body text, rather then just with small caps? I imagine there is, but the documentation is rather confusing.

Comment: You should be able to if you use the opentype fonts with Xe/LuaTeX or with ConTeXt. You cannot do this with the type1 fonts using (pdf)TeX with just the support files provided by the `antt` package. This doesn't mean that there is no way, of course. There is a way. But it is not a way which you probably will care to take. Since you don't give an example and don't give any indication which engine or format you are using, it is hard to say anything more useful.

Comment: @cfr Damn. Too bad. I don't use Xe/LuaLaTeX since no one supports them, so I don't want to bother learning how to do stuff that I'll never be able to actually use then get mixed up between versions.

Comment: The problem is that, as far as traditional TeX is concerned, the oldstyle figures are simply not part of the same font as the upright shape. So you can't access them without switching to a different font. This is just how the support package has been designed. As I say, it is perfectly possible to set things up differently. But that's not how `antt` has been designed. Shame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is straightforward with Xe/LuaTeX. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Antykwa Torunska}[Numbers=OldStyle]

\begin{document}

  A\,a
  B\,b
  C\,c
  Ch\,ch
  D\,d
  Dd\,dd
  E\,e
  F\,f
  Ff\,ff
  G\,g
  Ng\,ng
  H\,h
  I\,i
  J\,j
  L\,l
  Ll\,ll
  M\,m
  N\,n
  O\,o
  P\,p
  Ph\,ph
  R\,r
  Rh\,rh
  S\,s
  T\,t
  Th\,th
  U\,u
  W\,w
  Y\,y

  0\,1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6\,7\,8\,9

\end{document}
```

[image: oldstyle figures]

There is no way to do this with the type1 version of the fonts and just the support provided by the `antt` package. This does not mean that there is no way to do it in (pdf)TeX. There is certainly ***a*** way. But there is no straightforward way because the support package does not appear to have been written with the possibility of using oldstyle figures by default in ordinary text in mind.